# Copy single characters in C-string without pointers

Tags: c++

Here is the assignment:

Create a Cstring variable that contains a name, age, and title. Each field
is separated by a space. For example, the string might contain “Bob 45
Programmer” or any other name/age/title in the same format. Write a program using only
functions from cstring (not the class string ) that can extract the name,
age, and title into separate variables.

I extracted the name from the string, but I'm having trouble with getting any character after that. I can't use pointers because we haven't learned that yet so no strtok. I just need a direction to go because I am sure there is a function to make this easier. Thank you.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    char y[] = "taylor 32 dentist";
    char name[25];
    char age[4];
    char title[40];
    int i = 0;
    while (y[i] != ' ')
    {
        while (y[i] != '\0')
        {
            if (y[i] == ' ' || y[i + 1] == '\0')
            {
                break;
            }
            name[i] = y[i];
            i++;
        }
    }
    cout << "Name: " << name << endl
         << "Age: " << age << endl
         << "Title: " << title << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Solved:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>

using namespace std;

void separate_Variables(char y[], char name[], char age[], char title[]);

void output(char name[], char age[], char title[]);

int main()
{
    char y[] = "taylor 32 dentist";
    char name[25];
    char age[4];
    char title[40];
    separate_Variables(y, name, age, title);
    output(name, age, title);
    return 0;
}

void separate_Variables(char y[], char name[], char age[], char title[])
{
    int i = 0;
    int j = 0;
    while (y[i] != '\0' && y[i] != ' ') {
        name[j++] = y[i++];
    }
    name[j] = '\0';
    j = 0;
    i++;
    while (y[i] != '\0' && y[i] != ' ') {
        age[j++] = y[i++];
    }
    age[j] = '\0';
    j = 0;
    i++;
    while (y[i] != '\0' && y[i] != ' ') {
        title[j++] = y[i++];
    }
    title[j] = '\0';
    j = 0;
}

void output(char name[], char age[], char title[])
{
    cout << "Name: " << name << endl
         << "Age: " << age << endl
         << "Title: " << title << endl;
}
```

Comment: Make an iterator through `y` (you could call it `yi` or whatever), then make separate loops to extract each word.  Each time, you reset `i`, but not `yi`.  Normally you would wrap this up in a function, but I have to presume you have not "learned" functions yet either.  Besides, you'd want to use a pointer as a function argument anyway....

Comment: Okay cool, I get what you mean, have a counter for the whole string and have a sub counter for the words. We have learned functions, I just like to figure it out in main and separate it once I figure the problem.

Comment: Maybe worth looking at [std::strcspn](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/strcspn).

Comment: Why is the solution presented in the question?

Comment: @Martin I updated it to help anyone that needed it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You do not need nested loops - all you need is three loops one after the other.

The loops would look the same: take `i`-th character, compare it to space, and store in one of three destinations. When you see space, replace it with `'\0'`, and move on to the next destination:

```
int j = 0;
while (y[i] != '\0' && y[i] != ' ') {
    name[j++] = y[i++];
}
name[j] = '\0'; // Add null terminator
j = 0;          // Reset j for the next destination
i++;            // Move to the next character in y[]
... // Do the same thing for age and title
```

Comment: So I used that format and created a main counter for the string and a subcounter for to copy the characters, but it is not copying anything after the first loop. It gets the name, but is blank for age and title. Also, can you explain why we use the null terminator?

Comment: @urallsad I missed the `i++` part after the loop ([demo](http://ideone.com/OJkUop)).

Answer (score 0):

The outer loop needs to be testing for `'\0'`

The inner loop (now `!= ' '`) can be duplicated for each field. You need a separate index variable to separate i for y and where to put it for field (fi?)